# Laravel Dusk - how to run 10 tests at the same time (port 9515 issue)

Tags: php, selenium, connection, port, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel Dusk.

I create a function which I can run from the browser.

```
function search_availability() {
 $process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
    if ($process->isStarted()) {
      $process->stop();
    }
    $process->start();

    $options      = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]);
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)->setPlatform('Windows');

          $driver = retry(5, function () use ($capabilities) {
      return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 50000, 60000);
    }, 50);

    $browser = new Browser($driver, new ElementResolver($driver, ''));

    $browser->resize(1920, 1080);


    $html = $browser->visit('https://www.website.com');
// etc. ...
```

This process takes around 30 seconds and everything is fine when I run it 1-2 at the same time but when I create 10 tabs and run it simultaneously then first 2 tabs return me a response but other  return me errors like:

> Problem with simulation. Error: Curl error thrown for http GET to
>   /session/4d712f9861016c1057a251091e707907/screenshot
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
>
> Problem with simulation. Error: Curl error thrown for http GET to
>   /session/7af472d9a53ef80c41e93328dc57d01f/element/0.7938603297586027-35/attribute/value
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
>
> Problem with simulation. Error: Curl error thrown for http POST to
>   /session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"Windows","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--window-size=1920,1080","--no-sandbox"]}}}
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

10 test - 2 success and 8 fails - so as you can see every time problem is **Connection refused**

**MY questions:**

1. Can I change the port each time and prevent connection refused error
2. Can I change the number of allowed connections to port 9515
3. How many connections are allowed on the port 9515
4. Please suggest me a way to solve that problem and allow 10 tests at the same time...

**UPDATE:**

I write a code which will wait for the port to be free like:

```
try {
  $site = 'localhost';
  $port = 9515;
  for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
    $fp = @fsockopen($site,$port,$errno,$errstr,10);
if ($fp != false) {
  print "Port is used";
  sleep(10);

} else {

//run the function
```

and this code works fine but its not the perfect solution because only 1 user at a time can make request

Comment: What do you mean by "only 1 user at a time can make request"?

Comment: I build this as API (that API make some actions on websites) but when I run 10 requests (from 10tabs in browser) usually 50% are successful - 50% fails

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Why? Why sometimes I got error Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Did you know any solution for this problem? I run 10 tabs and 5 is successful but 5 fails

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but if you are able to give a different port number to each instance you are running, you can just specify a slightly different port for each chromedriver instance. In my case I am using paratest and can start up chromedrivers on different ports by overriding the base `TestCase` class like so:

```
<?php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        $port = self::getPort();
        static::useChromedriver('/usr/bin/chromedriver');
        static::startChromeDriver("--port=$port");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--window-size=1920,1080', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']);

        $port = self::getPort();
        $desiredCapabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
        return RemoteWebDriver::create("http://localhost:$port", $desiredCapabilities, 5000, 10000);
    }
    
    private static function getPort(): string
    {
        // Will be like 9501, 9502 etc. or 9515 by default
        // Ensure the port is unique when running paratest
        return '95' . str_pad(env('TEST_TOKEN', '15'), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone looking for a similar solution!